# Extract all data between multiple vertical bars

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with a mix of ASCII and hex data. I want to count the length of the string in bytes. The data between two vertical bars represent HEX data.

Example:  s = "2|00 00 00 06 00 00 00|Drives|24 00|". For this string, length should be 16 bytes since two hex digits represent one byte. I tried to extract the data between bars using regex: r'|.(.*?)|' but this matches the entire string. Any help? thank you

```
import re
s= "2|00 00 00 06 00 00 00|Drives|24 00|"
match = re.findall(r'|.(.*?)|', s)
```

Comment: But there are `9` pairs of hex digits here?

Comment: Yes but there is also a 2 at the start and 5 characters of Drives. Length counts both the ASCII and HEX data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to escape the `|` like `\|` to match the pipe, or else it would mean `or`. You might also leave out the dot in this part `|.(`

```
import re
s= "2|00 00 00 06 00 00 00|Drives|24 00|"
print(re.findall(r'\|(.*?)\|', s))
```

[Output](http://rextester.com/QKJ71495)

Comment: Thanks. I feel dumb for not noticing this. Can I also do a negative match to extract only the ASCII characters by using ! ?

Answer (score 1):

You could alter your approach and actually **look** for hex digits. A pair can be defined as

```
[a-f0-9]{2}
# a-f and 0-9 twice
```

---

Now, you'll only need boundaries on both sides and make it case insensitive, which in `Python` could be

```
import re

s = "2|00 00 00 06 00 00 00|Drives|24 00|"

rx = re.compile(r'(?i)(\b[a-f0-9]{2}\b)')

byte = len(rx.findall(s))
print(byte)
```

---

For your string this yields

```
9
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eyl8a5/1).

Comment: That seems interesting and perhaps more general. Only thing that I probably didnt clearly state is that length of a string should consider both the hex and ASCII. Moreover, the regex you proposed will give 9 matches (18 hexa digits). That should be 9 bytes. No need to multiply by 2.

Comment: @davideej: Changed the answer then, glad to help.

Comment: Thanks to you for helping. I have another question if you can help. Do inverse regexes exist too? Like If I want to match everything except the hex data from my string how would I go about it?